# Apply required tag CSS class to the required tags in the "how to ask" side bar

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta

When we ask a question, in the "How To Ask" side bar there is some information about the usage of the tags, such as support, bug and feature-request.

Since those are the required tags (with different color than other tags), can we apply the required tag CSS class to those tags.

**Current UI:**

[image: Current UI]

**Expected UI:**

[image: Expected UI]

Comment: As a meta post for Stack Apps only, in other Stack Exchange site, we have different description in the "How To Ask" side bar. In StackApps only the required tags are displayed in the side bar and my expectation is, the change is only for the StackApps site.

Comment: Okay, then use the meta tag for that.